# React Performance Profilng in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, performance, google-chrome, profiling, ag-grid-react

I'm doing some performance profiling using the Chrome developer tools on a SPA React (15.6) application that uses ag-grid-react, and I'm having a little troubling reconciling the output of the profiler with reality. For example, in the screenshot below, it looks like the connected drawer component's (Connect(Drawer), orange bar) "componentWillReceiveProps" method is taking ~2s, but there's nothing underneath that. I was skeptical after looking at the code that the method itself could possibly be taking that long, so I added some 'console.time' statements around all the code inside the function and low and behold:

> Drawer componentWillReceiveProps: 0.02001953125ms

Here's what my componentWillReceiveProps looks like, for reference:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.time('Drawer componentWillReceiveProps');
        if (nextProps.changes.length !== this.props.changes.length &&
            nextProps.changes.length === 0 &&
            this.state.isDiscarding) {
            this.setState({isDiscarding: false});
        }
        console.timeEnd('Drawer componentWillReceiveProps');
    }
```

So what am I missing here? I (kinda sorta) understand that the user timing api is only showing things that are marked (I'm just learning about this today, so my understanding of that api is limited to say the least...), so is it just the case that React isn't actually timing the stuff that's happening inside of componentWillReceiveProps? If it's useful, I'm using re-select and Redux, but I would assume that my selectors have already run prior to componentWillReceiveProps being called, but maybe I'm wrong about that?

Anyway, I think there's something fundamental that I don't understand about the Chrome flame charts, but I've read a bunch of articles and it's just not adding up for me.

**Update: Added componentWillReceiveProps implementation**

[image: react chrome profile]

**Update 2: Adding link to Chrome profile**

If anyone is interested in taking a look at the actual profile here's a link, you can view it by opening Chrome dev tools, going to the performance tab, and then clicking "load profile":

https://www.dropbox.com/s/72e9kwyxr0myec3/delete_react_perf_user_timing?dl=0

**Update 3: componentWillReceiveProps explanation**

OK, so it does seem that componentWillReceiveProps does (somehow) end up calling mapStateToProps, which would explain why it looks like it's taking so long in the profile. <del>I'm guessing that the componentWillReceiveProps call gets replaced by the redux connect method or something like that in order to do its thing, but I haven't verified that</del> **See the accepted answer.** Anyway, you can see evidence of this in the following screenshot:

[image: componentWillReceiveProps call stack]

Comment: What are the props that your Drawer is receiving? Look at the HEAP - during ComponentWillReceiveProps you see large changes in the memory use, going up 250MB then back down 350MB. I am not positive that there is any correlation between that and your performance problems however.

Comment: In the heap at the top of the screenshot it doesn't look like things are drastically changing heap-wise during that function call to me, am I reading it wrong?

Comment: Well, I can't hover over the chart to see the exact values, but it looks like it nearly doubles. I'm not saying that a 300MB change in your memory use SHOULD cause performance issues, but to me it shows that something is happening leading to an increase in memory use. Additionally, have you considered adding the performance console.log checks to the lifecycles both before and after componentWillReceiveProps?

Comment: Ah, sorry I was looking at before componentWillReceiveProps, but I see what you're saying, after componentWillReceiveProps is done the heap does jump up quite a bit. It's very strange because the code inside componentWillReceiveProps is very straight-forward and I can't see how it would be allocating any memory at all (all it does is check whether the length of one of the props has changed and set a simple state property...). Anyway, I'll keep digging I guess.

Comment: Yeah without seeing the code inside componentWillReceiveProps I don't think I can offer any other advice. I assume you are familiar with the warnings regarding this lifecycle hook, but in case you are not you should read through the docs here (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) and possibly refactor it out of your code to see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: I haven't read those docs in awhile, thanks for the link. I can try moving the code to compondentDidUpdate and see if that makes a difference or not, seems like that's currently the "right" place to put something like this (until I move to React 16). I updated my post above with my componentWillReceiveProps implementation, for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look closely at the flame chart, it's the `Connect(Drawer).componentWillReceiveProps` call that's taking a long time, **not the Drawer component itself**, which explains why my timing code inside the Drawer component was showing timing completely differently than the flame graph. The `Connect(Drawer)` component is a Higher Order Component whose whole purpose is to call mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps to map state and action creators to props on your component. In this case my `mapStateToProps` call was very slow, which explains the results in the graph.

As a side note, it would be great if react-redux added the User Timing API so that the mapStateToProps calls etc. would show up in the flame graph.

**TL;DR** Pay close attention to the actual component names in the flame graph.